# Topology and $\sigma$-algebra on the space of probability measures

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathbf{A})$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of sets, $\mathscr{M}(\mathbf{A})$ be the set of all $\mathbf{A}$-measurable functions $f\colon X\to [0,1]$, and $\mathscr{P}(\mathbf{A})$ be the set of all probability measures on $\mathbf{A}$. Let us equip $\mathscr{P}(\mathbf{A})$ with the structure of a topology as well as of a $\sigma$-algebra as follows.

Denote $\mathscr{B}$ the base of the standard topology on $[0,1]$ consisting of the intervals of the form $(a,b)$, $[0,b)$, and $(a,1]$ for $a,b\in[0,1]$, $a<b$.
Given a measurable function $f\in\mathscr{M}(\mathbf{A})$ and an interval $I\in\mathscr{B}$, denote $$R(f,I)=\left\{p\in\mathscr{P}(\mathbf{A})\colon\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}p\in I\right\}.$$
Let $\mathscr{R}=\big\{R(f,I)\!:f\in\mathscr{M}(\mathbf{A}),\ I\in\mathscr{B}\big\}$. Denote $\mathscr{T}$ the topology on $\mathscr{P}(\mathbf{A})$ generated by $\mathscr{R}$, and $\mathscr{S}$ the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathscr{P}(\mathbf{A})$ generated by $\mathscr{R}$.

**Question:** Is $\mathscr{S}$ necessarily the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with respect to $\mathscr{T}$? In other words, is $\mathscr{T}\subseteq\mathscr{S}$?

Comment: Presumably your open intervals $(a,b)$ should also include intervals of the form $[0,b)$ and $(a,1]$?

Comment: @NateEldredge Of course, thank you!